# Hide if source (computed token) field is empty

Tags: 8, hooks, webforms

I am setting up an event registration for an existing D8 website.

I have added content type Event with fields start date, end date etc.
And I have a webform for event registration with computed token field set.

Which hook should I use to run a pre-render validation on event date and hide the webform.

PS: I don't want to close the webform as it will be reused for multiple events in future.

I did check this (and many), but its marked as outdated does it mean functionality is there in the webform module?
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2877082

Comment: What exactly is your question again? "Outdated" in this case seems to mean that this feature request has already been addressed by the linked (and fixed) issues in the last comment.

Comment: I want to hide the webform if event's start date is less than or equal to current date